# Cakephp 3 shell script is staying in memory even after the job was finished

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron

I have a cakephp shell script that I run with Cron

```
bin/cake hello >/dev/null 2>&1
```

My `HelloShell.php`'s `main()` is like:

```
public function main()
{
    $this->loadModel('Hello');
    $Hello = $this->Hello;
    $Hello->doStuff($this->args);
    return 0; // I tried to add return but it didn't help
}
```

`HelloModel` uses another model, collects some info and saves it to the database.

Suddenly I've noticed that the process stays in memory even when everything's done and it should be closed.

I run `ps aux` in console and see

```
p1033     607670  0.0  0.0 106100  1132 ?        Ss   23:42   0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/xxxx/public_html/bin/cake hello do_stuff >/dev/null 2>&1
p1033     607676  0.0  0.0 295656 17400 ?        S    23:42   0:00 php /home/xxxx/public_html/bin/cake.php hello do_stuff
```

After a while another copy of the command starts by cron and it's also staying in memory until the owner of the server kills'em all.

I've tried to run a simple php script like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) sleep(1);
```

I saw that it appeared in the process list and disappeared after 10 seconds.

So, could anyone tell me what do I do wrong with cakephp?
What should I do to prevent processes to stay in memory after the job was done?

Comment: Well, I've found out that if I don't load any models and just use useless for loop - the process disappears after 10 seconds. Does it mean that I do anything wrong with DB? In the model I user ORM methods and ConnectionManager for some queries. And I call disconnect() method after that.

Comment: If I run the same job in console manually - it doesn't stay in memory after the job was finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about long sql scripts. Deadlocks or something like that.